# Printing the data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, printing

i am developing an ipad app where i need to print to a bluetooth printer. The printer does not have any other mechanism like wi-fi , it only has bluetooth.

i guess the ipads dont have bluetooth. it only has wi-fi. is there an app which prints to bluetooth printers?

Can ios4.2 detect bluetooth enabled printers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPad has bluetooth, however, AirPrint currently only works via WiFi.